# How to rename standard build-in function name?

Tags: php, security, exec, system, rename

Is there a way to change names of standard `system()` and `exec()` functions in PHP 5.2?

For some reasons, I need at least one of them, but can't keep it enabled too (for security reasons).

Comment: have tried any approches?

Comment: Have you considered opening the PHP documentation and typing something like "rename function" into the documentation search? Then, feel free to ask about using PECL and APD.

Comment: Yep, currently trying to use PECL runkit. But not sure, it's usable for standard functions?

Comment: The documentation states that `rename_function()` is "Useful for temporarily overriding built-in functions."

Comment: Re-reading your question... Renaming a disabled function will not enable the function. It only changes the name in PHP's function table.

Answer (score 1):

Security through obscurity is not security. The system you're using is preventing you from enabling those functions for a reason. Don't try to bypass it. Instead, find a better host.

With that said, you're still on 5.2? I guess you really don't care about security in the first place. I'd **STRONGLY** suggest stopping everything you're doing **right now** and getting upgraded to a maintained version of PHP >= 5.4 (and if you're paying for hosting, request a refund).

As far as how to rename built-in functions? There's no way to do it in the standard distribution of PHP. Yes, there are PECL extensions that let you do it, but they require special compilation.